# Populate javascript variable in loop to use for icon definition outside loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet api to create a map and place markers on it.  I've used a simple marker function found here: https://dotscrapbook.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/simple-numbered-markers-with-leaflet-js/

So this snippet of code works:

```
var numberIcon = L.divIcon({
 classname: "number-icon",
 iconsize: [25, 41],
 iconAnchor: [3, -40],
 html: 11
});

for (i=0; i<points.length; i++)

{

L.marker(points[i], {icon: numberIcon}).addTo(map1);
}
```

But this does not (but I need it to so I can populate the "number" variable within the for loop, sending it back up to the numberIcon).

```
var number;

var numberIcon = L.divIcon({
 classname: "number-icon",
 iconsize: [25, 41],
 iconAnchor: [3, -40],
 html: number
});

for (i=0; i<points.length; i++)

{
number = '11';

L.marker(points[i], {icon: numberIcon}).addTo(map1);
}
```

I must not be getting the scope right.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html` option of your `numberIcon` object is assigned the *value* of `number` at creation, i.e. before your loop. So `html` is `undefined`. This assignment is not re-evaluated later on, so it remains at `undefined`, no matter what the variable `number` becomes.

You could try re-assigning directly the `html` option within your loop (`numberIcon.options.html = '11'`), so that if your marker creates its icon right away, it will use an updated value of `html`. However, as pointed out by user 6502, all your markers now use the exact same icon object. So if for some reason, one of the marker needs to re-create its icon element (this happens for example when the marker is removed from map and added back), it will read the last value of `html`, which is probably not what you want.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/6/

It is usually recommended in Leaflet to instantiate one icon per marker, to avoid this issue.

See user 6502's answer for an example of doing so.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I'm basically only interested in displaying text data that will be refreshed occasionally, and I think your solution should take care of my needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess you need to create the `numberIcon` object inside the loop too...

```
var number;

for (i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    number = '11';
    var numberIcon = L.divIcon({
        classname: "number-icon",
        iconsize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [3, -40],
        html: number
    });
    L.marker(points[i], {icon: numberIcon}).addTo(map1);
}
```

`L.maker` is probably storing away the object and not making instead a shallow copy; reusing the same object in multiple calls to `L.maker` is going to create strange dependencies.