# How do I use my leaflet icon definition in my marker definition?

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet marker defined like this:

```
    var W0KCN3 = new L.marker(new L.LatLng(39.2859182,-94.667236),{
     opacity: 0.5,
     contextmenu: true, 
     contextmenuWidth: 140,
     contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',
     callback: circleKoords}], 
icon:  firstaidicon,
title:`marker_1 ` }).addTo(fg).bindPopup(`1<br>Northland ARES Platte Co. Resource Center<br>Kansas City, MO<br><br>39.2859182, -94.667236<br>EM29PG`).openPopup();
```

And I have an icon defined like this:

```
    // Define a PoiIcon class
var PoiIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize: [32, 37]
    }
});

// Create five icons from the above PoiIcon class
var firstaidicon = new PoiIcon({iconUrl: 'images/markers/firstaid.png'}),
    eocicon = new PoiIcon({iconUrl: 'images/markers/eoc.png'}),
    policeicon = new PoiIcon({iconUrl: 'images/markers/police.png'}),
    skywarnicon = new PoiIcon({iconUrl: 'images/markers/skywarn.png'}),
    repeatericon = new PoiIcon({iconUrl: 'markers/repeater.png'});
```

I want to use the firstaidicon in the marker definition but I'm struggling to make it work. 
I've tried:

```
icon:  firstaidicon,
```

But now I'm getting;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createIcon' of undefined
```

from all kinds of locations in leaflet.js:5
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each marker was being built by Ajax from a DB I think the timing of when thing happened led to the errors. By putting the icon definition inside the marker definition it all worked. So the new icon call is;

```
icon: L.icon({iconUrl: `images/markers/skywarn.png`, iconSize: [32, 34]}),
```

One line closer to being done.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [Leaflet Markers With Custom Icons tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/), you simply pass your custom icon variable to the `icon` option of your Marker:

```js
var firstaidicon = L.icon();

L.marker(latLng, {
  icon: firstaidicon // instead of new L.firstaidicon
});
```

Note: make sure to create a different icon instance (even with identical options) for each Marker. An easy way to do so is also shown in the tutorial, by *extending* the Leaflet Icon class:

```js
var firstaidiconClass = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconUrl: 'images/markers/firstaid.png',
    iconSize: [32, 37]
  }
});

L.marker(latLng, {
  icon: new firstaidiconClass
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to create a new icon instance for each marker if they have the exact same properties? Aren't they just "templates" to create the actual images on the map?

Comment: @nikoshr: that is a pitfall of Leaflet Icon unfortunately. For simple cases it does not matter indeed, but in edge cases it does create bugs. Typically when changing the icon instance options, possibly through Marker setIcon() as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579917/populate-javascript-variable-in-loop-to-use-for-icon-definition-outside-loop/33583356?r=SearchResults#33583356 and Leaflet [PR #1726](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1726)

Comment: I've adjusted my question to reflect the new code. But still getting the Uncaught TypeError from leaflet.

Comment: Hard to say with only code pieces and no reproduction example. Most probable reason I can think of as-is would be that you try using your icon variable before assigning it.